# How do I remove the comma from a CSV output?

Tags: java, csv

I'm outputting some results to a CSV in two columns so that I can create a basic graph. Due to the CSV format the values in my first column display as "10," I was wondering how I can remove the comma to make my data look neat.
Would I have to separate the data into columns in a different way or is their a way you can get the comma to not write to the CSV file?

```
    FileWriter wr = new FileWriter("Results.csv");
    wr.append(Integer.toString(r.length) + ", ");
    wr.append(Long.toString(execution_time));
    wr.append('\n');
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
```

Comment: You want to not write a C to a CSV file? That's just V. If you want it to line up when viewed with a monospaced font you need to pad the numbers appropriately based on their maximum size (in characters).

Answer (score 0):

```
FileWriter wr = new FileWriter("Results.csv");
wr.append(Integer.toString(r.length) +" ");
wr.append(Long.toString(execution_time));
wr.append('\n');
wr.flush();
wr.close();
```

this output a space instead of comma

Comment: @AlexJ You can't believe you didn't just remove the comma?

Answer (score 0):

Open this in Excel, so the CSV is opened as a xml file. Use this command removing the extra spaces:

```
    FileWriter wr = new FileWriter("Results.csv");
    wr.append(Integer.toString(r.length) + ",");
    wr.append(Long.toString(execution_time));
    wr.append('\n');
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use tab as separator:

```
FileWriter wr = new FileWriter("Results.csv");
wr.append(Integer.toString(r.length) +"\t");
wr.append(Long.toString(execution_time));
wr.append('\n');
wr.flush();
wr.close();
```